How to remove a broken snap package
I have a problem with my Darktable snap package which started when I moved to using the .deb package of Darktable. I don't remember what I did at the time but now I have snapd which tells me that darktable is installed, but any attempts to remove the package fails.
I tried remove, --purge remove, refresh, revert, disable/enable, I tried restarting with systemctl but nothing works.
In a desperate attempt I have deleted the snap user darktable folder and files (in /home/snap) and I also have removed the darktable.snap file in /var/lib/snapd/snaps which probably was stupid and will not help in solving this issue...
This is the output of snap list -all concerning the darktable package :
Nom                                   Version              Révision         Suivi               Éditeur             Notes
darktable                             -                           129       latest/stable    sergiusens         broken


And here are a few output errors with various commands :
sudo snap disable darktable
erreur : cannot perform the following tasks:
- Rendre indisponible le paquet Snap "darktable" (129)  pour le système (internal error: only regular files are supported, got "d---------" instead)

sudo snap remove --purge darktable
erreur : cannot perform the following tasks:
- Rendre indisponible le paquet Snap "darktable" pour le système (internal error: only regular files are supported, got "d---------" instead)

sudo snap refresh darktable
erreur : cannot perform the following tasks:
- Rendre indisponible la révision actuelle du paquet Snap "darktable" (cannot restore unlinked snap: internal error: only regular files are supported, got "d---------" instead)
- Rendre indisponible la révision actuelle du paquet Snap "darktable" (internal error: only regular files are supported, got "d---------" instead)

Output of  systemctl --failed :
  UNIT                     LOAD   ACTIVE SUB    DESCRIPTION                           
● snap-darktable-129.mount loaded failed failed Mount unit for darktable, revision 129

Output of systemctl start snap-darktable-129.mount
L'unité (unit) snap-darktable-129.mount a commencé à démarrer.
mount[45185]: mount: /snap/darktable/129: le périphérique spécial /var/lib/snapd/snaps/darktable_129.snap n'existe pas.
kernel: /var/lib/snapd/snaps/darktable_129.snap: Can't lookup blockdev
systemd[1]: snap-darktable-129.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited, status=32/n/a

So I don't think it's related to darktable, probably something went wrong at some point when I tried to remove/reinstall/update the darktable snap package, but I don't know what.
Now I don't really know what to try.
The only problem is that it prevents me from reinstalling the darktable snap package (if I ever wanted to...).
Thanks for any tips !

It may still be possible to remove it and all its dependancies by going to Ubuntu Software, search for Darktable (the Snap version if that is what you have installed) and click on the wastebasket icon. If the .deb` version is still installed and causing a problem, perhaps delete and reinstall it

@graham thanks for the tip but I do not see the snap version of Darktable in Ubuntu Software... I used to see it (in the "Updates" tab) but could not make it go away, and that's how I understood that there was a problem. Besides I do not have any problem with the .deb version that is working fine for me.

does this AU Question help at all?

@graham I had seen this AU question but it does not help since I have no changes "doing" when listing snap changes. Thanks anyway.
